# Blank Page on redirect in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to redirect to another controller home.php after succesfull login, but somehow the url is pointing to the correct  controller but i am getting a blank page , even if i try echo  "something"; die; in index() of home.php it does not display the echoed message.

My controller codes are:

login.php

```
    function index(){
        //if Admin already logged in, send to Admin home

        $this->data['message']='';
        $this->data['msg_class'] = '';
        $post_array=$this->input->post();

        $data['old_images']=$this->mod_common->getBgImages();

        if($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on')
        {
            //echo $this->input->cookie('username');
            $this->data['message']=strip_tags($this->mod_login->check_cookie_login());
            if($this->data['message']=='Login Successful'){
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';

                 redirect('home');              
            }else{
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
            }
        } 
        if($this->input->post('action')=='adminLogin'){

        //print_r($this->input->post()); die;

            if(isset($post_array['remember'])){
                $username_cookie= array(
                    'name'   => 'uusername',
                    'value'  => $post_array['username'],
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => FALSE
                );

                $password_cookie= array(
                    'name'   => 'userpass',
                    'value'  => $post_array['userpass'],
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => FALSE
                );

                $remember_cookie= array(
                    'name'   => 'remember',
                    'value'  => 'on',
                    'expire' => '865000',
                    'secure' => FALSE
                );

                $this->input->set_cookie($username_cookie); 
                $this->input->set_cookie($password_cookie); 
                $this->input->set_cookie($remember_cookie); 
                //die;

            }
            else
            {
                if($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on')
                {
                    if($this->input->cookie('uusername') != $post_array['username'])
                    {
                        delete_cookie("remember");
                        delete_cookie("uusername");
                        delete_cookie("userpass");
                    }
                } 
            }

            $this->data['message']=strip_tags($this->mod_login->validate_admin_login());
            if($this->data['message']=='Login Successful'){
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
                /* this is where it is taking the home page from */
                 redirect('home');              
            }else{
                $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
            }
        } /*else if(isset()){

        }*/


    ///////////////////////
        $this->data['cookieRemember'] = $this->input->cookie('remember');
        $this->data['cookieUsername'] = $this->input->cookie('username');
        $this->data['cookiePassword'] = $this->input->cookie('userpass');
        //echo $this->data['cookieRemember'];echo $this->data['cookieUsername']; echo $this->data['cookiePassword'];
    //////////////////////

        $this->data['cookiename']  = $this->input->cookie('name', false);
        $this->data['cookieimage'] = $this->input->cookie('image', false);

        $sess_msg = $this->session->userdata('session_msg');
        $session_msg_class = $this->session->userdata('session_msg_class');
        if(isset($sess_msg) && $sess_msg!= ''){
            $this->data['message']=$sess_msg;
            $this->data['msg_class'] = $session_msg_class!=''?$session_msg_class:'gagal';
        }
        //render full layout, specific to this function

        $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
    }
```

home.php (The redirected controller)

```
    function index(){
        global $USER;

        $data = array();
        //if Admin already logged in, send to Admin home
        #$this->data['maincontent'] = $this->load->view('maincontents/gridview',$data,TRUE);
        $data['lastlogin_details']  = $this->admin_lastlogin_details();

        $data['thought_day']        = $this->mod_common->getPageDesc('thoughtOfTheDay');
        if($this->input->post()) { 
         $post_array            = $this->input->post();
         $data['comments_msg']  = $this->mod_common->save_comments($post_array);
         $data['announcement_id']= $post_array['announcement_id'];
        }else{
         $data['announcement_id']= $data['announcements'][0]['id'];
        }
        $data['announcements']      = $this->mod_common->get_announcements(4);
        $announcements_likes        = $this->mod_common->get_announcements_likes();
        foreach($announcements_likes as $al)
        {
            $data['announcements_likes'][]= $al->announcement_id;
        }
        $comments_likes     = $this->mod_common->get_comments_likes();

        foreach($comments_likes as $al)
        {
            $data['comments_likes'][]= $al->comment_id;
        }

        if($data['announcements'][0]['id']!= '')
            $data['announcement_comments']=$this->mod_common->get_comments_by_id($data['announcements'][0]['id']);

            $data['workspace']  = $this->mod_common->get_workspace();

        $data['gallery'] = $this->mod_common->get_array_frontend_raw('pr_gallery');

        $data['count_bday_serComp'] = $this->mod_common->count_bDay_serComp();
        $data['count_newjoinees']   = $this->mod_common->count_new_joinees();   


        //$data['category_name']        =$this->mod_common->get_category_by_id(1);
        $data['birthdays']          = $this->mod_common->get_birthdayList();
        $data['service_completion']=$this->mod_common->get_serviceCompletion();
        $data['new_joinees']=$this->mod_common->get_newJoineesList();
        $data['quick_links'] = $this->mod_common->get_cat_array2('pr_quicklinks','','','title');

            $this->data['maincontent']  = $this->load->view('maincontents/dashboard',$data,true);

        $this->load->view('layout', $this->data);
    }
```

Comment: Any error message?. if not go to your index.php turn on your error_reporting

Comment: It should be self-explanatory that you cannot run PHP within the Code Snippets feature of this website.  As the boxes are clearly labeled, it's only for live demos of HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  Edited.

Comment: Also, please do not tag-spam.  The code cannot be part of CodeIgniter version 2 and version 3 at the same time.  Edited.   Only use the tag for the relevant version.